# listproperty GAE to string method

Tags: python, json, google-app-engine

So my problem below is that when it sends the json object lets say I have multiple items in the lists? well it sends that many objects except changing that field once in the dict that i created above. For some reason , even though I use the for loops above to create a string from the list it doesn't actually make it so and i get 15 objects instead of 1 object with maybe a field that has 15 things in it separated by commas.
my expected output should be 
name,special1,special2,special3..etc, review1,review2

instead i get
name,special1,review1
name,special2,review1
name,special3,review1
etc..
name,special1,review2
name,special1,review3

My main question is how do I convert the list to an array or even just to a string(like a toString Method) so that my json dump doesn't spit out multiples?

```
 class store(db.Model):
    mykey = db.StringProperty(db.Key)
    storeSpecial = db.ListProperty(item_type=str)
    reviews = db.ListProperty(item_type=str)
    storeName = db.StringProperty()

#later in the code
    qy1 = GqlQuery("SELECT storeName,storeSpecial,reviews FROM store WHERE mykey =:1",dataInput)

    records_to_send = []
    for i in qy1:
        rev =""
        for k in i.review:
            rev = rev + str(k) + ","
        spec = ""
        for k2 in i.storeSpecial:
            spec = spec + str(k2) + ","
        output = {"store name": i.storeName,"specials": spec,"reviews":rev}
        records_to_send.append(output)
    self.response.out.write(json.dumps(records_to_send))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you want, your example is confusing. If you use JSON, why not just keep it as list? Why do you change it to a string?

It seems you want something like this

```
for store in qy1:
    records_to_send.append({'store name': store.storeName, 'specials': store.storeSpecial}, 'reviews': store.reviews})
```

Comment: well because when i leave it as a list for example i get this back when I run a curl post statement:
[{"store name":Sears,"specials": spec1,"reviews": rev1},{"store name": Sears,"specials":spec2,"reviews",rev1},..etc until end of both lists]

what I want is [{"store name":Sears,"specials": list of all specials,"reviews": list of all reviews},"store name": walmart, "specials": list of all specials,"reviews": list of all reviews}]

Comment: I believe what you want is what you supposed to get. It will be somethinge like [{store name: name1, specials:[list of special1], rev:[list of special2]}] Have you check your data in datastore? or have you tried my code above?

Comment: Yes I used to have it with just the lists but then i got a serializable error. I then switched it to what I have above to just extract the list as a string just like the name to send it. I went back to the lists per your suggestion and I still get the same results. in the datastore, its just stored as list ( reviews and specials). I don't undestand that if I had 2 items in the list, why it needs two json objects  instead of 1 that has said name, and contains the entire list and not just one element of it.